# How to run asynchronous flask API requests

Tags: python, flask, asynchronous

I know that flask is sync and not async like fast API but I need to use flask, my mission is to call to API route multiply time and each time it would need to call a async function to run in the background until it finish running. This is my current script:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import asyncio

app = Flask(__name__)

async def async_function():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("Background function completed")
    
@app.route('/async')
async def async_route():
    await asyncio.gather(
        async_function()
    )
    return jsonify({"result": "Function registered to run in the background after 5 seconds."})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The only problem in my code is that it wont succeed to run asynchronous, it wont return me the response from `/async` until it finish to run the function...
I would need your help to solve this.

Comment: Flask has full async support

Comment: Flask still depends on the WSGI server to support asyncio. I recommend to take a look at https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/aioflask.

Comment: First of all flask is not async by default, but if it does so why it wont work? try running it yourself

Comment: at least you need to run an asyncio event loop to make those coroutines work

Comment: Can u give me examples on how to run asyncio event loops?